# Android | bookmark icons on homescreen

Tags: android, web, icons, homescreen

**bookmark and add to my homescreen 60x60 icon does not apprear.** 
Make

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/iphone.png"/>
```

Size: 60x60 pixels. tried 8bit and 24bit ping! Does not work. Site is on a localhost and not 'online'.

on http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport if I bookmark and add to my homescreen it works! **Why?**
They use: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/sol/shared/img/iphone-sport.png"/>`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7):

For Android to pick up the icon you need a precomposed icon

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/>
```

Also mentioned here [Configuring Android Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951381/configuring-android-web-applications)

Comment: thank you :)) sorry for the reaction delay. Appreciate your answer

Comment: Keep in mind for many Android devices, a full path needs to be specified as well otherwise the icon may not show up - see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7657 for more info

Answer (score 1):

Add 57x57 png image without any effects like glossy, transparent. Code for the bookmark icon is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://devw3.com/devw3-icon/57x57.png" />
```

We can use the same code for iphone, ipod touch and ipad but the icon sizes will differ. You can find more about options sizes and how to configure for different devices here: [Adding Bookmark Icon On Home Screen IPhone, IPad, IPod Touch And Android](http://devw3.com/html/adding-bookmark-icon-on-home-screen-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-and-android)