# Add a favorite / bookmark icon for Android

Tags: android, web-applications, favicon

Is there a way to customize a favorite or bookmark icon for Android?

I know for Apple it's `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favIcon.jpg">` or a regular website it's `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favIcon.jpg">`

but for Android I'm still left with this image on the springboard [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android | bookmark icons on homescreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215047/android-bookmark-icons-on-homescreen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android to pick up the icon you need a precomposed icon

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/>
```

For more details see these links:

1. [Android Bookmark icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215047/android-bookmark-icons-on-homescreen)
2. [Configuring Android Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951381/configuring-android-web-applications)

Comment: works fine for me without precomposed, on a Nexus S (still on 2.3.7 though)

Comment: it might just be a device issue. my Incredible had just the flag before, now with the pre-compressed it adds the icon inside the flag (not perfect, but better than just the flag itself) and my Xoom now shows just the icon, exactly how i want it.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung SII apple-touch-icon-precomposed is also displayed in the bookmark flag.
That's ugly. It have upgraded to Android 4.0 ICS few weeks ago, I think that it is the problem. In the previous version of Android (3.xx), the icon was the one expected.