# Android HTML5 add shortcut icon to home screen not consistant

Tags: android, html

We have HTML5 mobile website, when we try to add the site to the 'Home screen' by add to home screen icon. It doesn't work consistently. It shows the app icon sometime, sometime it shows default star icon.

Why android browser behaves like this? Is there any way to make this behaviour consistent.

We already tried,
http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2010/06/web_app_homescreen_icons_in_android.html
[Android | bookmark icons on homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215047/android-bookmark-icons-on-homescreen)
[Configuring Android Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951381/configuring-android-web-applications)

No success :(

Answer (score 0):

https://realfavicongenerator.net/ does a good job at generating icons for all types of browsers.