# How to change the default Android bookmark icon?

Tags: android, icons, favicon, homescreen

I keep getting the default Android ribbon bookmark icon, instead of my 114x114 icon for web app. Ideas?

I have tried ...

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png"/>
```

I have also tried an approach similar to: 
    if (useragent == blackberry){
    use precomposed/use 114x114-precomposed
    }

In all variations, I continue to get the default ribbon icon, with the favicon centered in the middle of the ribbon.  Isn't it possible to create a home page icon in Android that looks like a native app?

I have iOS and BlackBerry devices handled, but I am having no luck with Androids.  It also doesn't seem to matter what browser I use.

Do I need to have **full path** including domain location?  Other ideas?

Comment: android uses the favicon.ico I think.

Comment: I am reading in the last comment [here](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/android-apple-touch-icon/) that "It works for me if I add it as a bookmark and then add to home screen."  There must be a way to do this directly without having the user jump through a hoop.

Comment: I can't get that to work either, using the above variations.  I would prefer not to use the favicon if that is possible.

Comment: I can't find a definitive "no" anywhere. Regular Android users?  What's your experience?  Have you bookmarked a web app and had the full icon show up?  If so I would be interested in the link.

Answer (score 1):

take à look at this ;)

[Configuring Android Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951381/configuring-android-web-applications)

or this

http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2010/06/web_app_homescreen_icons_in_android.html

this

it should work, it may not work because your path is not the right one, make sure your image is at the root of your web server because you included '/' before your path