# What is mobile script in html for android?

Tags: android, asp.net, html

If I want to use my web site in iphone I write this code. But I dont know how can I do this for android? Can you help me, what is code for android to use in my web site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
  content="yes" />
              <script>
function BlockMove(event) {
// Tell Safari not to move the window.
event.preventDefault() ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it would works for android too

Comment: Well if it's "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", then it probably doesn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the home screen Android will use:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/custom_icon.png"/>
```

As described in [Configuring Android Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951381/configuring-android-web-applications)